# CKEditor - multiple instances of same class

Tags: ckeditor

I have an existing application that has several divs with a class.

What I'd like is to have each of these to have the [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) available to them, i.e

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="myContent">some Text</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="myContent">some Text</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="myContent">Some Text</div>
```

This works by not having any of the `CKEDITOR.XX`, but the problem Is I want to have a custom menu for the divs.

Can you do this with classes?

I've only seen: `var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable' );` where `editable` is HTML `ID`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. You can modify `config.js` file which is placed in main CKEditor directory, setting configuration there (for all editors).
2. Or you can use `CKEDITOR.inline` which accepts HTML element **or** id/name as [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) say.

   ```
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myContent' );
   for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
       CKEDITOR.inline( elements[ i ], { /* config for this instance */ } );
   }
   ```

   Although this won't work on IE7&8, so using jQuery you can do:

   ```
   var elements = $( '.myContent' );
   elements.each( function() {
       CKEDITOR.inline( this, { ... } );
   } );
   ```
3. 3rd option is to overwrite `CKEDITOR.config.toolbarGroups` globally.

Comment: What would go in: `CKEDITOR.inline( this, { ... } );`

Comment: Configuration. Like in previous example.